# angularjs $cookieStore SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, angular-cookies

Have you got any ideas why I get an error

*SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character*

on this code

```
console.log($cookieStore.get('XSRF-TOKEN'));
```

the cookie value is

*kscJcqrDYSMdZtBleuq8yUrB*

?

### UPDATE NODE CODE

```
var currentSession = req.session.passport;
var user = currentSession.user;
res.cookie('USER',JSON.stringify(user) , { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: false});
```

Comment: Maybe it is the dash, have you tried escaping it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[$cookieStore](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore) is serialized session storage. It gives you error because value of cookie are not serialized.

You need [$cookies](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) for your value.